# Resolve function pointer in $(document).ready(function(){}); by json string name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a json object retrieved from server in my `$(document).ready(...);` that has an string that I would like to resolve to a function also defined within `$(document).ready(...);` so, for example:

```
$(document).ready(function{

    $.getJSON(/*blah*/,function(data){/*more blah*/});
    function doAdd(left,right) {
        return left+right;
    }
    function doSub(left,right) {
        return left-right;
    }
});
```

with json string:

```
{"doAdd":{"left":10,"right":20}}
```

One way I thought about was creating an associative array of the function before loading the json:

```
var assocArray=...;
assocArray['doAdd'] = doAdd;
assocArray['doSub'] = doSub;
```

Using `eval` or `window[]();` are no good as the function may not be called for some time, basically I want to link/resolve but not execute yet.

Comment: Are you saying the functions are defined in the Javascript, but the args are defined in the JSON, or are the functions themselves defined in the JSON?

Comment: @kojiro - Functions are defined in the javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your JSON to

```
{method: "doAdd", parameters : {"left":10,"right":20}}
```

Then do

```
var method = eval(json.method); 
// This doesn't call it. Just gets the pointer
```

Or (haven't tried this)

```
var method = this[json.method]
```

Comment: I added method and parameters key because otherwise you have to check what the key is using an if statement. Probably not what you want.

Comment: @Amir - Thanks, this did it and also cleared up my mis-understanding of `eval` - Frank

Comment: The `this` method should be favored over `eval` here.

Comment: @Frank - you are welcome. And kojira is correct because eval raises a lot of security issues.

Comment: I will try `this` but it didn't work, although my perception may have been clouded by 48 oz of coffee. I assume you mean `var func = this['funcName']`?

Comment: Yes. In javascript this.foo == this['foo']

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
$(function(){
    // Function to be called at later date
    var ressolvedFunc = null;

    // Ajax call
    $.getJSON(/*blah*/,function(data){
        // Generate one function from another
        ressolvedFunc = (function(data) {
            var innerFunc;
            var left = data.left;
            var right = data.right;

            // Detect action
            for (action in data) {
                if (action == "doAdd")
                    innerFunc = function() {
                        return left + right;
                    };
                else
                    innerFunc = function() {
                        return left - right;
                    };
            }

            return innerFunc;
        })(data);
    });
});
```

The anonymous function returns fresh function, with the new values stored within the enclosure. This should allow you to call the function at later date with the data previously retrieved from the GET request.

Rich

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
   var doX = (function() {

        var 
           data = [],
           getDo = function(action) {

               for(var d in data) {
                   if (data[d][action]) {
                       return data[d];
                   }
               }

               return null;  
           };

        return {
             set: function(sdata) {
                 data.push(sdata);
             },
             doAdd: function() {
                 var add = getDo("doAdd");

                 if (!add)
                     return 0;

                 return add.doAdd.left + add.doAdd.right;
             },
             doSub: function() {
                 var sub = getDo("doSub");

                 if (!sub)
                     return 0;

                 return sub.doAdd.left + sub.doAdd.right;
             }
       };

    })();

   $(document).ready(function{

        $.getJSON(/*blah*/,function(data){ doX.set(data); });

    });
```

Comment: This isn't very clear. If I am in an function (i.e. doAdd)... how did I get there if not calling it and therefore making the `getDo` redundant?

Comment: Since I have now expanded my understanding of self-executing functions I can appreciate what you were doing... mea culpa

Comment: @Frank C., ok, no problem, I hope you work for another to solve a problem or other situation